# Multidex: Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Tags: android

I just updated my SDK to 5.0, and appcompat v7 r21

after that in my project I get this:

```
Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

How can I solve that? I don't use gradle.

Comment: this issue is not come when we update sdk 5.0 i also updated this is like as per methed support by android system

Comment: Your project is too large. You have too many methods. There can only be 65536 methods per application

Comment: I know what is the error, but how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google just released multidex. Theres an Blog Post

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

I had same issues like you. I removed Guava from the Project and just took those classes i needed from it. Not always an option, i know.

Comment: A solved the probleme just cutting out what I didn't use from my google_play jar file. (there was a lot of methods)

Comment: thats can cause other problems as you dont have the source.